# Which CSS selector is correct for my trigger?

Tags: css, google-tag-manager, selector

I would very much appreciate your help with the following issue:

On all my posts with a row of three toggle elements like on https://internationalgreeter.org/destinations/aisne I would like to fire a tag (in GTM) if one of the toggles is opened with click.
Which would be the correct css selector in my trigger? I tried differents bits of the whole "Click element" but did not succeed.
If possible I would like to detect **only the opening clicks** but not the closing clicks.

This is what GTM displays as "Click element":

HTMLHeadingElement: html.js > body.post-template-default.single.single-post.postid-35116.single-format-standard.dbdb_divi_2_4_up.desktop.et_pb_button_helper_class.et_fullwidth_nav.et_fixed_nav.et_show_nav.et_primary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade.et_secondary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade.et_header_style_left.et_pb_footer_columns1.et_cover_background.et_pb_gutter.windows.et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.et_no_sidebar.et_divi_theme.et-db.gecko > div#page-container > div#et-main-area > div#main-content > div.container > div.clearfix#content-area > div#left-area > article.et_pb_post.post-35116.post.type-post.status-publish.format-standard.has-post-thumbnail.hentry.category-destinations.category-europe.category-france.tag-europe#post-35116 > div.entry-content > div.et-boc#et-boc > div.et-l.et-l--post > div.et_builder_inner_content.et_pb_gutters3 > div.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_1.et_section_regular > div.et_pb_row.et_pb_row_5.3-buttons-row-class#3-buttons-row > div.et_pb_column.et_pb_column_1_3.et_pb_column_3.et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough > div.et_pb_module.et_pb_toggle.et_pb_toggle_0.toggle_meetalocal-class.et_pb_toggle_item.et_pb_toggle_close#toggle_meetalocal-id > h2.et_pb_toggle_title

Thanks a lot in advance.
Klaus
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. The preview tool is useless with the Click Element variables. It tries to represent them as a generic selector, but fails miserably. It's an extremely misleading flaw that the GTM team should fix.
2. Therefore, screenshots from the debugging tool are pretty useless for the Click Element variable.
3. You want to start your work in DOM and work with your CSS selectors from there.

Whenever you want us to help you write your CSS-selectors you should always give us the block of HTML around the clicked element. Please supply HTML and we'll help you with the selector.

Ok, try this selector: `div#3-buttons-row, div#3-buttons-row *`

Comment: Hi BNazaruk,
I am sorry but due to my lack of CSS knowledge I was not able to put my question in a better way.
Now I copied that part of the page source code that I would regard as covering the row with three toggle elements.
Currently I am using a trigger checking if Click classes equals et_pb_toggle_title. But it is firing on other pages with toggle elements too and excluding the wrong ones is difficult. 
So here is the code (separate answer to my question):

Comment: Ok, try this selector: `div#3-buttons-row, div#3-buttons-row *`